# Check if the function is differentiable at $P=\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The function is given as:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2}}, \ \ &\text{if }\ \  x^2+y^2<1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ , \ \ &\text{if } \ \ x^2 + y^2 \ge 1
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
Check if the function is differentiable at $P=\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)$.

---

Some of my intuitions say that $f$ should be differentiable at that point, so I'm trying to prove this by definition.

I've found out that $f(P)=0$ and  $f'_x(P) = f'_y(P)=0$. So, if it is differentiable, the following statement should be true:
$$f\bigg(\frac 1 2 +\Delta x, \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2} + \Delta y\bigg)=f(P)+f'_x(P)\Delta x + f'_y(P)\Delta y + o\bigg(\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}\bigg) $$
which in our case comes down to show that:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(\frac{1}{2}+x, \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$
Now,  now we can go to $P$ from inside the circle or outside the circle.

- From outside the circle:

The numerator becomes $0$ so does the limit. We're done.

- From inside the circle:

So, we set the condition $(\frac{1}{2}+x)^2 + (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + y)^2 < 1$. Then, the above limit becomes
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\cfrac{e^{-\cfrac{1}{1-(x+1/2)^2-(y+\sqrt 3/2)^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
Now, if I wanted to switch to polar coordinates, how would I this? Shall I substitute $(x,y) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ or $(x+1/2,y+\sqrt 3/2) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$. In both cases, the limit becomes kind of ugly...

Well, I took the first option, so that the limit became
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\cfrac{e^{\cfrac{1}{r(\cos\theta+\sqrt 3 \sin \theta)+r^2}}}{r}$$

Am I going the correct way?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is an idea on how to finish the proof. When we put $(x,y)=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, note that, since we are assuming that it is coming from inside the circle, we have $(x+1/2)^2 + (y+\sqrt{3}/2)^2<1$, which is equivalent to
$$
r^2 + r(\cos\theta + \sqrt3\sin\theta) <0.
$$
Moreover, since $\cos\theta + \sqrt3\sin\theta \geq -1-\sqrt 3$, we have
$$
0>r^2 + r(\cos\theta + \sqrt3\sin\theta) \geq r(r -1-\sqrt 3) > -(1+\sqrt3)r.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{e^{\dfrac{1}{r^2 + r(\cos\theta + \sqrt3\sin\theta)}}}{r} < \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{(1+\sqrt3)r}}}{r} \xrightarrow[r\to0_+]{} 0.
$$

Comment: When $h>0$, $(1/2+h)^2+(\sqrt 3/2)^2 \ge 1$. Hence, your limit is $0$ as the original function is defined as $0$ outside the unit circle.

Comment: Oooooops! Deleting...